# How to use SharedPreferences to store persistant data Android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

I am building a camera application. I'm trying to save some information using SharedPreferences.
I want to save some persistant information-the last image taken filepath. But the first time the application is used before taking a picture, the data would be NULL.

So I want to getSharedPreferences in onCreate and check if the value is null. But as far as I know the only way to use getSharedPreferences is only if you have called put on the Editor before. Hence, I am getting a NULL pointer exception on the SharedPreferences object the first time.

How do you resolve this?

```
     //inside on Create()
      imageData = getSharedPreferences("ImageData",MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = imageData.edit();

    prefEditor.commit();
    String previousImage = imageData.getString("lastImageTaken", null);
    if(previousImage == null){

        Log.d(TAG,"previous image is NULL");
    }
    else{
        //do something with the filepath            

        }
  //-----------------------
//in onClick of capture button
imageData = getSharedPreferences("ImageData",MODE_PRIVATE);

            SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = imageData.edit();
            prefEditor.putString("lastImageTaken", MyActivity.this.pictureFilePath);
            prefEditor.commit();
```

Comment: can u shed some light on `String previousImage`, is it in shared prefs?

Comment: What is use of SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = imageData.edit();

    prefEditor.commit(); those llines?

Comment: Your code shouldn't generate a null pointer exception, even if it does, it has nothing to do with the SharedPreference's non-existence. Post your stacktrace, maybe we can find something there.

Comment: @Pankaj: The SharedPreferences object does not have any memory allocated to it. And we can't say new SharedPreferences. It says in the documentation that if the first argument to getSharedPreferences does not exist then the edit() call will create it. That's why I tried to put those 2 lines inthe hope of allocating memory to it. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Aki: You're right, I don't get  the NUll pointer exception with the above code. I had encountered it when the put and commti lines were commented and I was getting the exception at the imageData.getString line because imageData was null. Now, even if I comment the 2 lines as previously, I odn't get any exception because I think that the null value has been written into the preferences. I'm not entirely sure of what's happening. I can only guess.

Comment: @Namratha: so did i diagnose the NPE correctly? check my first comment

Comment: @android_hungry: The String previousImage is stored in SharedPreferences as you can see in  prefEditor.putString("lastImageTaken", MyActivity.this.pictureFilePath. I'm trying to retrieve that String.

Comment: @Namratha: in `oncreate` obviously it will be null because u r trying to retrieve something that was never put

Comment: @android_hungry: Exactly! It's like a paradox. Because the first time only will it be null. There's no way of knowing that unless I have some flag which must also be written into some persistant memory location. So how does this work?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this
To read from SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String name = preferences.getString("name","default");
    String email = preferences.getString("email","default");
```

To save into SharedPreferences

```
Editor edit = preferences.edit();
                   edit.putString("name", "Roy");
                   edit.putString("email", "roy@mail.com");
                   edit.commit();
```

Comment: Sandy is correct, there is an attribute that will save a default value if it is currently null.